# Android calling JS function return wrong values

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am calling JavaScript via WebView. This is my code:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
.....

   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, final String url) {
       super.onPageFinished(view, url);
       view.loadUrl("javascript:Android.showAdBanner(showSdkAd())");
       view.loadUrl("javascript:Android.updateUrl(appUrl())");
   }
}


public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface {
   ....

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showAdBanner(boolean appUrl) {
       if (appUrl) {
            ...
       } else {.....}
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void updateUrl(String appUrl) {

       if (appUrl.isEmpty()) {
         ....
       }

       if (appUrl.equals("m.url.de")) {
         ....
       }
    }
}
```

`showSdkAd()` returns a `boolean` value and `appUrl()` returns a `String`.

The problems is that I get the wrong values, always `false` when the `showSdkAd()` function is called and an `empty String` from `appUrl()`.

I've already checked it and it works on the server side, so the problem should be on my side.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Try to replace with this view.loadUrl("javascript:Android.showAdBanner(showSdkAd())"); to
view.loadUrl(your_url);

Comment: Actually I don´t know the Url, it is given by the appUrl() JS function.

Comment: Try temporarily substituting the calls to `showSdkAd()` and `appUrl()` with some constants, e.g. `true` and `http://example.com` respectively in your `onPageFinished` code, and see whether you are getting those values in your injected object correctly. It is possible that you are calling `showSdkAd()` and `appUrl()` too early.

Also note that in Java you need to compare Strings using `equals` function, e.g. `"m.url.de".equals(appUrl)`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: When I substitute the calls with some constants it works :( . Thanks for the type about compare strings!